# Send information from Roboflow

Tags: python, roboflow

Send information from roboflow to my web create by django .

precisely I want send vlaue class to my web

I want the easiest way to solve this problem

Note that my internet is somewhat weak

First time here and I hope you can help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.